# SQL Server 2016でdatetime列のwhere句とorder by句を同時に指定すると100倍以上遅くなる

Tags: sql, sql-server

一部名前を変え忘れた箇所があったので質問を上げなおしました。申し訳ございません。

logsテーブル 500万行 30列くらい
logs_subテーブル 500万行 20列くらい logsテーブルと1対0または1

上記のテーブルから一定の期間のレコードを取得するため
datetime型(datetime2ではない)の列で検索を行う必要があるのですが、
where句とorder by句を同時に指定すると100倍以上遅くなります。

```
--遅くない
select *
from logs l
left join logs_sub ls
on l.logdate = ls.logdate
and l.id1 = ls.id1
and l.id2 = ls.id2
and l.id3 = ls.id3
and l.id4 = ls.id4
where logdate between @start and @end

--遅くない
select *
from logs l
left join logs_sub ls
on l.logdate = ls.logdate
and l.id1 = ls.id1
and l.id2 = ls.id2
and l.id3 = ls.id3
and l.id4 = ls.id4
order by logdate

--100倍以上遅い
select *
from logs l
left join logs_sub ls
on l.logdate = ls.logdate
and l.id1 = ls.id1
and l.id2 = ls.id2
and l.id3 = ls.id3
and l.id4 = ls.id4
where logdate between @start and @end
order by logdate
```

テーブル定義

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[logs](
    [logdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [id1] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [id2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id3] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id4] [int] NOT NULL,
    --ほかいろいろ
 CONSTRAINT [pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [logdate] ASC,
    [id1] ASC,
    [id2] ASC,
    [id3] ASC,
    [id4] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[logs_sub](
    [logdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [id1] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [id2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id3] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id4] [int] NOT NULL,
    --ほかいろいろ
 CONSTRAINT [pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [logdate] ASC,
    [id1] ASC,
    [id2] ASC,
    [id3] ASC,
    [id4] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

- 今よりも速く、datetime列でソートされた値を取得する必要があります。
- 検索結果が100万件以上になることもありますが、そのすべてを取得する必要があります。
- インデックスを追加することはできません。

クライアント側でソートを行う以外にできることはありますか？

Comment: 念のための確認ですが「100倍以上遅く」は複数回実行して得られた結果でしょうか？ キャッシュ等の影響で偶然発生した問題ですと原因究明は困難ですので。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

クエリをどう解釈し、どう実行されたかは[実行プランを表示](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-and-save-execution-plans?view=sql-server-2016)することで確認できます。３つのクエリを比較してみてください。比較結果をふまえて効率的なクエリに書き換えることができるかもしれません。

これは実行プランを見ずにの当てずっぽうの案ですが

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM logs WHERE logdate BETWEEN @start AND @end) AS l
LEFT OUTER JOIN logs_sub AS ls
ON l.logdate = ls.logdate
AND l.id1 = ls.id1
AND l.id2 = ls.id2
AND l.id3 = ls.id3
AND l.id4 = ls.id4
ORDER BY l.logdate
```

と絞り込んでから結合してみるのはどうでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

実行プランを見ていろいろ試した結果、
クラスター化インデックスの項目をすべてorder by句に含めることで
order by無しと同じくらいのパフォーマンスが得られたことをここに報告します。
ありがとうございました。

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM logs WHERE logdate BETWEEN @start AND @end) AS l
LEFT OUTER JOIN logs_sub AS ls
ON l.logdate = ls.logdate
AND l.id1 = ls.id1
AND l.id2 = ls.id2
AND l.id3 = ls.id3
AND l.id4 = ls.id4
ORDER BY l.logdate, l.id1, l.id2, l.id3, l.id4
```